# Unable to Upgrade VS Project from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

Running VS version 15.9.4, I followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) (I think), but I'm still having trouble upgrading an existing 2.1 project to the latest stable (2.2.3).

**Here is my dotnet --info**
[image]

**And here is my project file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;DEBUG_LOCALAPI</Configurations>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <None Include="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PublishingAPICommon\PublishingAPICommon.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**If I try to install 2.2.3 to that project from NuGet manager, this is the error message I get:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET
>   Core 2.2. Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of
>   the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2. PublishingStorage C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.502\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets    137

**And here is what I see in VS when I try to edit the project properties directly:**
[image]

**Things I have tried:**

1. Re-starting VS
2. Re-starting my machine
3. Creating a project-scoped global.json file with 2.2.3 value

Answer (score 0):

From @martin-ullrich on https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11844

> Go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 and
>   download the installer for the 2.2.105 version. Anything >= 2.2.200
>   will not work in VS 2017. Both 2.2.105 and 2.2.202 contain the latest
>   and greatest .NET Core 2.2 version but they differ in the version of
>   the tools they include and are based on - the 1xx train is MSBuild
>   15., NuGet 4. etc. and the 2xx train is MSBuild 16., NuGet 5. and so on and Visual Studio only looks for the latest version compatible with
>   its version of MSBuild - for VS 2017 this is 2.1.502 version which
>   cannot target .NET Core 2.2. (And to add more confusion, there are now
>   2.1.6xx versions with VS 2019 tool versions together with the .NET Core 2.1 runtime)
>
> [@]leecow and [@]rowanmiller are working on updating that page
>   regarding VS, also see dotnet/core#2542 and dotnet/sdk#3076 which are
>   about the same problem.

---

**My contribution:**  After installing 2.2.105, I deleted the folder(s) titled '2.2.202' in directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk` and/or `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` so that dotnet --info now reads the following:
[image]